# Best approach to matrix representation of system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have this system of ODEs:
$$
\frac{dS}{dt}=\pi S-\beta S Z\\
\frac{dZ}{dt}=\alpha S Z - \delta Z
$$

I am trying to rewrite them in the form :

$$
\pmatrix{\dot{S}\\\dot{Z}}=\mbox{diag}(S,Z) \left(b+A\pmatrix{S\\Z}\right)
$$

What is the best approach for this? I've solved it such that :
$$
A=\pmatrix{0 ~~~~-\beta\\\alpha~~~~~~~~0}
$$
$$
b=(\pi, -\delta)^T
$$
But this was pretty slow, I was wondering what the most effecient approach would be for this and similar more difficult problems.

Comment: what do you mean by slow ? are you attempting to solve it numerically ?

Comment: @hickslebummbumm in order to solve them numerically on R I want to rewrite them in the form shown, I've currently solved for b and A, but i was wondering what the optimal way to do that was since finding them took me a long time

Comment: To me it seems like "the right way". And your needing a long time to find $A$ and $b$ seems quite unrelated to the correctness to me.

Comment: @hickslebummbumm my question has nothing to do with the correctness of my solution, I am asking what is the most efficient way to go about solving for A and b, as I am not currently happy with the way I did it

Comment: Then my apologies for misunderstanding you. It seems like a feasible system to solve as your problem contains only two unknowns, the amount of flops during each recursion of for example forward Euler should be quite limited.

Comment: but my question is about the fastest way to find the matrices A and b? How would you go about converting into matrix form, my method was mostly trial and error, I think there must be a more efficient approach @hickslebummbumm

Comment: Oh I see. Well you could say $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, sandwich it with $(S,Z)$ and $(S,Z)^T$ multiply everything and just match both sides of the equation, i.e. find your parameters $a,b,c,d$. But I can tell you once you have done that a couple of times it's gonna be child's play. I have done similar things for much larger systems and it's really not a problem once you're used to it.